# Vue 3 Typescript Class Component - Type 'typeof import(.../node_modules/vue/dist/vue")' is not a constructor function type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-class-components

Hi I'm using Vue 3 with Typescript and Class Components. I just copy-pasted the example from the docs but it looks like there is an issue with Typescript:

```
TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  This expression is not callable.
    Type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/vue-class-component/dist/vue-class-component")' has no call signatures.

TS2507: Type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/vue/dist/vue")' is not a constructor function type.
```

The docs: https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html

Does anybody know what is missing? Thanks!

[image: The Error]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/416) there's no need to that decorator and the imports are different for the version  3

```
<template>
  <div>{{ message }}</div> 
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component'

export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  message="Hello World"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! As you pointed out Component will be renamed to Options. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/406

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The solution resolves the first error, on the `Component` decorator. But the error on `Vue` is still here...

Comment: can you please clarify more your second issue

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me nuts.  I'd been working with Vue and TypeScript in VS Code happily (well, ish) for a while, and thought I'd have another go at using class-style components.  I get this:

[image]

Or lots of people suggest using this old format:

[image]

It was so frustrating!  I'm sure if I was fluent in TypeScript I could debug the Vue files, but surely the whole point is that they provide a black box solution?

But after hours of searching, when I was about to give up, I found this posted by Patrice Ferlet on dev.to:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-facing-decorator'

@Component
export default class ClassComponentExample extends Vue {
  message = 'wow'
}
</script>
```

And it works!  Turns out you now need to use vue-facing-decorator. Who knew?